# Google Play Services web scoreRank

Tags: html, web, google-play-services, google-plus

I'm using Leaderboards and Achievements of Google Play Service for Android apps and web (html5). Everything works fine except "**scoreRank**" parameter on web (https://developers.google.com/games/services/web/api/scores/list  *playerScore.scoreRank*).

Problem:

- if the Player **has account** on Google Play Games (that's registered on android phones) and player enters with this account on web game (with the same gmail, google+) then "scoreRank" is got **okay**
- if the Player **doesn't have** Google Play Games account and connects to web game via Google+ then "scoreRank" **isn't worked** and Player doesn't appear into leaderboards list. Nevertheless other parameters are got and submitted good.

there're the some console logs:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hV4Ft.jpg)

How to use leaderboards, without of the required registration on Google Play Games, just via Google+?

Or maybe, is there way to register on Google Play Games on desktop browser?

Comment: You might want to check this [Google Play game services - Web basic samples](https://github.com/playgameservices/web-basic-samples), to see if there is something or implementation you missed. It is behaving weird as a user's gmail without a google game account first logged in the app only gets that scenario. If you feel that this is a [bug](https://github.com/playgameservices/web-basic-samples/issues/new) feel free to file a ticket in their issue tracker. Don't forget to post any update so that this can help the community.

Comment: Mr.Rebot, thank you for the link, checked, the same situation (http://piponga.com/tmp/web-basic-samples-master/type-a-number-js/index.html)
I'll create the ticket